# Setting environment variables in nix via a shebang

Tags: nix

Is it possible to set environment variables while using nix-shell which gets invoked via a shebang? For example, I'm using

```
#! /usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i runghc --pure
```

and would like to set an environment variable like `FOO=bar`. Note, `FOO` is not necessarily defined by the surrounding environment. Thus `--keep FOO` is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using an accompanying `shell.nix` file. You could simply define your environment variable as a derivation attribute there.

shell.nix

```
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [ pkgs.ghc ];
  shellHook = ''
    VIA_SHELL_HOOK=it\ works   # no it doesn't
  '';
  VIA_DRV_ATTR = "working";
}
```

Example executable script

```
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#!nix-shell -i runghc --pure

import System.Environment(getEnv)

main = do
  getEnv "VIA_DRV_ATTR" >>= print
  getEnv "VIA_SHELL_HOOK" >>= print
```

Output:

```
"working"
hello: VIA_SHELL_HOOK: getEnv: does not exist (no environment variable)
```

(Nix 2.3.4, Nixpkgs 20.03)

Comment: I'm not using an accompanying shell.nix file. However, I wasn't even aware that this is possible while using a shebang. So your solution works perfectly well for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do make the `nix-shell` 'interpreter' do it without a `shell.nix`. In such a case you may be able to resort to setting the environment variable at the start of the script or the start of `main`. If you need to set a variable before the real interpreter runs, `shell.nix` is currently the only option.

Comment: I'm already experimenting with `shell.nix` :-) Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to set environment variables when utilizing nix with shebang.

### nix as main language in a single file with bash shebang

```hs
#! /usr/bin/env -S bash -c 'nix-shell --pure $0'

with import <nixpkgs> {};
let
  haskellCode = ''
    import System.Environment (getEnv)

    main = do
      getEnv "VIA_DRV_ATTR" >>= print
      getEnv "VIA_SHELL_HOOK" >>= print
  '';
in
mkShell {
  buildInputs = [ ghc ];
  shellHook = ''
    export VIA_SHELL_HOOK="VIA_SHELL_HOOK works"
    exec runghc <<< '${haskellCode}'
  '';
  VIA_DRV_ATTR = "VIA_DRV_ATTR works";
}
```

```sh
$ ./test.nix 
"VIA_DRV_ATTR works"
"VIA_SHELL_HOOK works
```

The drawback is that haskell code gets embedded in a nix string.

### haskell (or any other) as main language in a single file with nix shebang

```hs
#! /usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i runghc --pure -E "with import <nixpkgs> {}; mkShell { buildInputs = [ ghc ]; VIA_DRV_ATTR = \"VIA_DRV_ATTR works\"; shellHook = ''export VIA_SHELL_HOOK=\"VIA_SHELL_HOOK works\"''; }"

import System.Environment (getEnv)

main = do
  getEnv "VIA_DRV_ATTR" >>= print
  getEnv "VIA_SHELL_HOOK" >>= print
```

```sh
$ ./test.hs
"VIA_DRV_ATTR works"
"VIA_SHELL_HOOK works"
```

The drawback is the lengthy shebang nix-shell line with escaped quotation marks. There doesn't seem to exist a way to break it into several lines.

### both nix and another language in a single file with shebang?

Maybe it's possible to compose 2 language blocks one after another and write some generator script in shebang line in the manner of [combining bash and haskell](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang#Haskell).

### [haskell (or any other) in a file with nix shebang with accompanying `shell.nix` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62250979/1663197)